# MySQL check if comma separated values match rows in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how I can query my table to see if a group of user_id's match a conversation_id.

**Query 1 should return result for:**
user_id 1 is looking to see if there are any conversation_id's with just user_id = 2 and user_id = 1 in it. (Should return a row for each conversation_id = 1, 2, 4, 5 based on SQL Fiddle example)

```
conversation_id
1
2
4
5
```

**Query 2 should return result for:**
user_id 1 is looking to see if there are any conversation_id's with user_id = 2, user_id = 1, **and user_id = 4** in it. (Should return 0 rows as it doesn't exist in the SQL Fiddle example)

The table setup is located at 
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29019a/3/0)

Comment: The question title mentions comma separated values, but the rest of the question doesn't. Where does the comma separated values come into the picture?

Comment: I mean it like how you wrote this part  "and user_id not in (1,2)". Looking over your answer and testing it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `group by ... having` and a correlated `exists` subquery to achieve the result you want:

```
-- Query 1:

SELECT 
  conversation_id
FROM 
  users_conversations uc
where not exists (
  select 1 from users_conversations
  where conversation_id = uc.conversation_id
  and user_id not in (1,2)
)
group by conversation_id
having count(distinct user_id) = 2;

-- Query 2: same query, only different numbers.

SELECT 
  conversation_id
FROM 
  users_conversations uc
where not exists (
  select 1 from users_conversations
  where conversation_id = uc.conversation_id
  and user_id not in (1,2,4))
group by conversation_id
having count(distinct user_id) = 3;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29019a/30)

Note that the first query will not return `1,2,4,5` but rather `2,5` but in your sample data neither 1 or 4 has only user_id 1 and 2 as participants (`conversation 1` has `1,2,3,4`, and `conversation 4` has `1,2,5`).

Answer (score 1):

If i understand it right it should be something like his.

Q1:

```
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN
count(distinct CASE WHEN user_id in ('1','2') THEN user_id END)>='2' 
THEN `conversation_id` 
END 'test'
FROM 
users_conversations
where 1
group by `conversation_id`
```

Q2:

```
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN 
count(distinct CASE WHEN user_id in ('1','2','4') THEN user_id END)>='3' 
THEN `conversation_id` 
END 'test'
FROM 
users_conversations
where 1
group by `conversation_id`
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb29d/9